# Execute select query from code behind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, code-behind

How can i execute a `SELECT` query from my Code Behind file and then iterate through it?

I want to do something like this (just a simple pseudo example):

```
// SQL Server
var results = executeQuery("SELECT title, name FROM table");

foreach (var row in results)
{
    string title = row.title;
    string name = row.name;
}
```

How can i do this within code?

Comment: [Here you go](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f(v=vs.80).aspx)!

Comment: Do you know SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader or SqlDataAdapter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
 string queryString = 
    "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        queryString, connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                reader["OrderID"], reader["CustomerID"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

The `connectionString` will vary depending on the Database product and the authentication mechanism used (Windows Auth, username/password, etc.). The example above assumes you are using SQL Server. For a complete list of different `ConnectionStrings`, go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: this is not viewing anything in my case.